# Cancel a HTTP request

Tags: angular, typescript, http, get, httprequest

I would like to know if there is any way I could check if a HTTP get is in pending status and if there is a way to cancel my HTTP get?

This is my HTTP get:

```
public getData(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get('http://IP_ADRESS:3490/testStream', {responseType: 'arraybuffer', observe: 'response' }});
}

public putData(): void {
   this.getData().subscribe((resp) => {
     console.log(resp);
     const responseArray: Uint8ClampedArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(resp);
     const newTabTemp: Uint8ClampedArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(this.maxHeight * this.maxWidth * 4);
     let comp = 0;
     for (let i = 0; i < this.maxHeight * this.maxWidth * 4; i = i + 4) {
       newTabTemp[i] = responseArray[comp];
       newTabTemp[i + 1] = responseArray[comp];
       newTabTemp[i + 2] = responseArray[comp];
       newTabTemp[i + 3] = 255;
       comp = comp + 1;
     }
     let nouvData: ImageData;
     nouvData = new ImageData(newTabTemp, this.maxWidth, this.maxHeight);
     this.contextVideo.putImageData(nouvData, BORDERX / 2, BORDERY / 2);
   });
}
```

[image: Request taking to much time]
[image: Request never suceeding]

I'm getting a lot of these pending requests that never succeed or that take a long time to. How can I check if they're pending and cancel them?

Comment: You can unsubscribe from observable it will have the effect of cancellation

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 2+, if you call unsubscribe on the request observable, the request will abort. The natural behaviour of subscription.unsubscribe() is not to abort the request, but angular 2 guys have added this specific functionality in angular/http package. Please refer [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0cb4f12a7a57087ec4e8329a04d5dfc430764b45/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts) Angular github repo.

In normal scenarios (when not using angular/http), if you want to abort the request on unsubscribe, you may leverage below code -

```
Observable.create((observer) => {

        function cancelRequest() {
            // Clear any even listeners added previously.

            request.abort();
        }

        // Other request processing related code

        request.send(formData);

        return () => {
            cancelRequest();
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Cancelling an HTTP request is a common requirement. For example, you could have a queue of requests where a new request supersedes a pending request and that pending request needs to be cancelled.
Sign in to comment

To cancel a request we call the unsubscribe function of its subscription

```
 @Component({ /* ... */ })
    export class AppComponent {
      /* ... */

      search() {
        const request = this.searchService.search(this.searchField.value)
          .subscribe(
            result => { this.result = result.artists.items; },
            err => { this.errorMessage = err.message; },
            () => { console.log('Completed'); }
          );

        request.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
```

Courtesy: [Cancel http request](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/http/catching-rejections/cancel_request.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unsubscribing from observable has same effect of cancellation. In the example below the http request will be cancelled in 2s. You can view the full example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XQL8v9?p=preview)

```
search() {
const request = this.searchService.search(this.searchField.value)
  .subscribe(
    result => { this.result = result.artists.items; },
    err => { this.errorMessage = err.message; },
    () => { console.log('Completed'); }
  );

setTimeout(() => request.unsubscribe(), 2000);
```

}